How do I calculate covariance as numeric value for 10 realizations of simulated data?
Description
I am estimating the number of change points by applying the DepSMUCE method using stepR package in R, and it requires calculating the covariance as a numeric vector.
I have generated data and calculated covariance as a numeric vector using the formula. When I try to estimate the change points, I get the error message
Error in .familyMDependentPS(data = data, y = y, ...) : 
   covariances have to be a finite numeric vector.

Attempt
library(stepR)
set.seed(1234)
f <- rep(c(0, 2, -2, 2, -2), c(200, 200, 200, 200, 200))
y <- as.data.frame(
  replicate(10, f + arima.sim(list(ar=c(.9)), n=1000, sd=.4358899))
)
correlations <- function(x) {
  (acf(arima.sim(list(ar=c(.9), ma=c()), n=1000, sd=.4358899), lag.max=1))$acf
}
cor <- sapply(y, correlations)
covar <- function(cor) .4358899^2 * cor
cova <- lapply(cor, covar)
covariances <- lapply(cova, as.numeric)
x <- seq(.001, 1, .001)
fit <- function(X) {
  stepFit(X, x=x, alpha=.1, family="mDependentPS", covariances=covariances,
          jumpint=TRUE, confband=TRUE)$rightIndex
}
cp <- sapply(y, fit)


Why are you doing lapply(cova, as.numeric), actually it does nothing. And where is covariances= passed to?

@FriedeThank you for prompt response. Actually, your code gives numeric value with 20 data points. How over, for my case I need 2 data points for each variable (each realization). I tried according to your code, but I am getting the same error.

@Friede x <- f + arima.sim(list(ar=c(.9)), n=1000, sd=.4358899) may not be required as far as I need y. But I should define x <- seq(.001, 1, .001) for stepFit function to estimate the change points.

@Friede yes, you are right. I want to map each column of y to stepFit(). So, I need two  values of covariances for each column to map to stepFit(). I will remove y[1:10] since it is the same as y. Thank you for your comments.

The error message you're encountering indicates that the covariances argument you're passing to the stepFit function needs to be a finite numeric vector. Let's check the structure of your covariances object to see if it meets this requirement.
It seems like you're trying to calculate covariance for each variable in your dataset and store them in a list named covariances. However, the structure of covariances seems to be a list of numeric vectors. The stepFit function expects a single numeric vector for the covariances argument, not a list.

@Friede, I did as per your comments but still I am getting the same error. May be you can check the code by installing stepR package; please help me.

@VladimirPetukhov, definitely you got my idea. I tried your code but still I am getting the same error. May be you can run and check the code by installing stepR package. Thanks in advance for your help.

Too long for a comment.
Is this what you are looking for?
library(stepR)
set.seed(1234) 
f = rep(c(0, 2, -2, 2, -2), c(200, 200, 200, 200, 200)) 
y = as.data.frame(
  replicate(10, f + arima.sim(list(ar = c(.9)), n = 1e3, sd = .4358899)))
correlations = as.numeric(acf(
  arima.sim(list(ar = c(.9), ma = c()), n = 1e3, sd = .4358899), lag.max = 1)$acf)
covariances = .4358899 ^ 2 * correlations
lapply(y, \(y) stepFit(y = y, x = seq(.001, 1, .001), alpha = .1, 
                       family = "mDependentPS", covariances = covariances, 
                       jumpint = TRUE, confband = TRUE)$rightIndex)

returns
$V1
 [1]   88  164  174  200  228  295  319  391  400
[10]  431  452  488  533  600  635  673  724  779
[19]  800  826  843  922  959  986 1000

$V2
 [1]   29   63  103  209  281  380  400  430  517
[10]  529  537  590  600  609  631  685  719  800
[19]  889  906  961  971  994 1000

$V3
 [1]   39   60   76   95  163  237  252  320  358
[10]  400  461  471  539  600  656  718  786  800
[19]  862  975 1000

$V4
 [1]   39   51   72  102  167  200  253  269  334
[10]  363  389  400  415  474  585  600  625  689
[19]  800  923  968  988 1000

$V5
 [1]   72  100  112  150  200  222  270  280  339
[10]  359  400  432  467  525  567  600  635  725
[19]  800  814  874  915  961 1000

$V6
 [1]   79  100  112  197  219  263  278  321  367
[10]  400  481  502  569  600  660  686  735  752
[19]  800  901  916  952 1000

$V7
 [1]   16   53   77  113  147  172  201  223  257
[10]  351  400  432  447  485  577  600  632  711
[19]  729  788  800  842  875  905  949 1000

$V8
 [1]   48  117  126  140  178  201  228  253  327
[10]  342  400  436  465  546  600  668  746  800
[19]  847  872  953 1000

$V9
 [1]   43   88  139  199  252  304  383  400  448
[10]  468  527  574  600  666  706  731  766  786
[19]  800  826  868  922  936 1000

$V10
 [1]   51   68  157  181  259  279  329  350  387
[10]  400  452  481  520  574  600  628  646  668
[19]  724  761  800  818  832  882  910  929  957
[28] 1000


I have re-written your attempt a bit. If you are seeking explanation, just let me know.

EDIT
y-dependent: (1) calculating covariance according to your scheme; (2) Mapping each column of y and respective cov to stepFit().
library(stepR)
set.seed(1234) 
f = rep(c(0, 2, -2, 2, -2), c(200, 200, 200, 200, 200)) 
y = as.data.frame(
  replicate(10, f + arima.sim(list(ar = c(.9)), n = 1e3, sd = .4358899)))
covfun = \(y) c(acf(y, lag.max = 1, plot = FALSE)$acf) * .4358899 ^ 2
cov = lapply(y, covfun)
Map(\(y, cov) stepFit(y = y, x = seq(.001, 1, .001), alpha = .1, 
                      family = "mDependentPS", covariances = cov, 
                      jumpint = TRUE, confband = TRUE)$rightIndex, 
    y, cov)

returning
$V1
 [1]  111  171  200  228  295  316  391  400  431  452  488  533  600  635
[15]  673  731  779  800  826  843  922  959  986 1000

$V2
 [1]   29   63  103  209  281  380  400  430  517  529  537  590  600  609
[15]  631  685  719  800  889  905  961  971  994 1000

$V3
 [1]   39   60   76   95  163  237  252  320  358  400  461  471  539  600
[15]  656  717  786  800  862  975 1000

$V4
 [1]   39   51   72  102  167  200  253  269  334  363  389  400  415  474
[15]  585  600  625  689  800  923  968  988 1000

$V5
 [1]   72  100  112  150  200  222  270  280  339  359  400  432  467  525
[15]  567  600  635  725  796  800  814  874  915  961 1000

$V6
 [1]   79  100  112  197  219  263  278  321  367  400  481  502  569  600
[15]  660  686  735  752  800  901  916  952 1000

$V7
 [1]   16   53   77  113  147  172  201  223  257  351  400  432  447  485
[15]  577  600  632  711  729  788  800  842  875  905  949 1000

$V8
 [1]   48  117  126  169  200  228  253  327  342  400  436  465  546  600
[15]  668  746  800  847  872  953 1000

$V9
 [1]   43   88  139  199  252  304  383  400  448  468  527  574  600  666
[15]  706  731  766  786  800  826  868  922  936 1000

$V10
 [1]   51   68  157  181  259  279  329  350  387  400  452  481  520  574
[15]  600  628  646  668  724  761  800  818  832  882  910  929  957 1000

